# How to tell Automapper to check if all source properties have destination properties

Tags: c#, validation, mapping, automapper, automapper-2

We have two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping configuration

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>;
```

Is there some possibility for Automapper to check automatically that all source properties have corresponding destination properties, in my example throwing an exception which notifies us about **Foo.C** property not mapped to anything. *Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()* checks only the other way round - that all destination properties have source properties so it doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Maybe you can try to reach [@JimmyBogard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard) as he is the creator of [tag:automapper]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a hack and test the mapping in the other direction. Something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, Foo>; // Swap the direction of the mapping
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
```

I know it isn't ideal but could be a quick solution.

Comment: Nice point though I'd prefer not to have mappings that are used just for testing purposes and are in fact invalid.